# XAML fanout button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a button control in WPF/XAML similar to those in Windows 10 (and Windows 8.1 I think) onscreen keyboard? By that I mean when held down, they "fan out" into multiple buttons that can be dragged over to and activated when released (even if click is released slightly away from the key). If not, how to implement them?

[image: The picture is worth a thousand characters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a default control to do this. However, I think you can get this functionality by:

1) Having a button that has your main text selection
2) Creating a popup with a grid of buttons containing the default value along with all the variations you want to display
3) Keeping the styling of the main button and the ones in the popup consistent
4) When the popup is shown, position it so the main text button aligns with the one shown in the popup.

Here is a example of some of this. 
FanoutButton.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="FanoutButtonTest.FanoutButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="64" d:DesignWidth="64" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnMain" Background="#FFF6F6F6" Click="btnMain_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class FanoutButton : UserControl
    {
        private string _mainText;
        private Popup _fanoutPopup;

        public string MainText { get { return _mainText; } set { SetMainText(value); } }

        public List<string> Variations { get; set; }

        public delegate void ValueClickedHandler(string value);
        public event ValueClickedHandler ValueClicked;

        public FanoutButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeVariables();
        }

        private void InitializeVariables()
        {
            this.Variations = new List<string>();
        }

        private void SetMainText(string value)
        {
            _mainText = value;

            btnMain.Content = _mainText;
        }

        private void Hold()
        {
            //Calculate rows and columns for popup
            int buttonCount = 1 + this.Variations.Count;
            double squareRoot = Math.Sqrt((double)buttonCount);
            int columns = (int)Math.Ceiling(squareRoot);
            int rows = (int)Math.Round(squareRoot);

            int width = (int)this.Width * columns;
            int height = (int)this.Height * rows;

            //Get button location
            Point buttonPosition = btnMain.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));

            _fanoutPopup = new Popup();
            _fanoutPopup.Width = width;
            _fanoutPopup.Height = height;
            _fanoutPopup.HorizontalOffset = buttonPosition.X;
            _fanoutPopup.VerticalOffset = buttonPosition.Y;


            var allValues = new List<string>();
            allValues.Add(_mainText);
            allValues.AddRange(this.Variations);

            var container = new WrapPanel();
            _fanoutPopup.Child = container;

            foreach (string value in allValues)
            {
                var button = new Button();
                button.Width = this.Width;
                button.Height = this.Height;
                button.Content = value;
                button.Background = btnMain.Background;
                button.Foreground = btnMain.Foreground;
                button.Template = btnMain.Template;
                button.Tag = value;
                button.Click += button_Click;

                container.Children.Add(button);
            }

            _fanoutPopup.IsOpen = true;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string value = "";

            if (sender is Button)
            {
                value = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();

                _fanoutPopup.IsOpen = false;

                RaiseValueClicked(value);
            }
        }

        private void btnMain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Hold();
        }

        private void RaiseValueClicked(string value)
        {
            if (ValueClicked != null)
            {
                ValueClicked(value);
            }
        }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window xmlns:FanoutButtonTest="clr-namespace:FanoutButtonTest"  x:Class="FanoutButtonTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <FanoutButtonTest:FanoutButton x:Name="fbtnTest" Width="48" Height="48"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow Code Behind:

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

```
    fbtnTest.MainText = "a";
    fbtnTest.Variations = new List<string>() { "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
    fbtnTest.ValueClicked += fbtnTest_ValueClicked;
}

private void fbtnTest_ValueClicked(string value)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked: " + value);
}
```

}